# How do I read image data from a URL in Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

What I'm trying to do is fairly simple when we're dealing with a local file, but the problem comes when I try to do this with a remote URL.

Basically, I'm trying to create a PIL image object from a file pulled from a URL.  Sure, I could always just fetch the URL and store it in a temp file, then open it into an image object, but that feels very inefficient.

Here's what I have:

```
Image.open(urlopen(url))
```

It flakes out complaining that `seek()` isn't available, so then I tried this:

```
Image.open(urlopen(url).read())
```

But that didn't work either.  Is there a Better Way to do this, or is writing to a temporary file the accepted way of doing this sort of thing?

Comment: See also: [How to save an image locally using Python whose URL address I already know?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8286352/562769)

Comment: There must be an issue where the requests is not able to fetch the image from the url. Try the same ( just for testing purpose) from another url.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The following works for Python 3:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests

im = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
```

References:

- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/1151
- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#280-2015-04-01

Comment: urllib2 was for Python2 I think, which is outdated. For Python 3 it's urllib.requests: `urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()`

Comment: As mentioned by @wordsforthewise urllib is outdated. I used the second option as I was using 'requests' anyway in my code and it worked, so upvoting. Should the urllib part of the solution be removed so that readers don't spend time on trying the first approach just to realize that it doesn't work and then move to the next one?

Comment: Hi this worked great for my project! Just wondering, does this build up any buffer or cache? Do I need to close these images / clear anything?

Answer (score 451):

In Python3 the StringIO and cStringIO modules are gone.

In Python3 you should use:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
```

Comment: How to get back the image from response.content ?

Comment: `requests` package throws 503 status code while fetching an image from a URL. Instead, I had to resort to `http.client` to get the image.

Comment: When I try this I get: AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'.

Comment: Manually wrapping in BytesIO is no longer needed since PIL >= 2.8.0.
Just use ```Image.open(response.raw)```. 
PIL automatically checks for that now and does the BytesIO wrapping under the hood.
From: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/releasenotes/2.8.0.html

Comment: @ViníciusM your answer should be at the top! thank you

Comment: Kinda annoying that 3 libraries are necessary... Pillow should just add this functionality!

Answer (score 173):

Using a `StringIO`

```
import urllib, cStringIO

file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(URL).read())
img = Image.open(file)
```

Comment: Thanks, would just like to add that the same exact code will work with urllib2 (with Python2)

Comment: in python 3 it would be from urllib.request import urlopen and io.io.BytesIO instead of StringIO

Comment: HELP, IOError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fb91b6a29b0> my url is: ...model=product.template&id=16&field=image_medium

Answer (score 62):

Using `requests`:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(StringIO(response.content))
```

Comment: For some reason urllib didn't work for some URLs, but requests worked where that failed

Comment: I couldn't find the PIL package, but it looks like pillow have taken over the PIL effort and you can install for python3 with `pip3.4 install pillow`.

Comment: Note that requests will load the entire response into memory, and then PIL will load the entire thing again as an image, so you have two full copies resident in memory.  The previous answer using urllib method streams the data, so you only end up with one copy plus the streaming buffer size.  You can stream the data with requests too, but because the response does not support read() semantics, you would have to build an adapter.

Comment: @sirdodger Are you referring to urllib2 or urllib?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I was referring to the accepted urllib answer.  If memory overhead is a concern, it is better than using this requests answer.  (However, like I mentioned, a different solution using requests could achieve the same effect.)

Comment: @sirdodger PIL Apparently now supports the streaming too. =) 
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/releasenotes/2.8.0.html

Answer (score 52):

## Python 3

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(urlopen(url))
img
```

## Jupyter Notebook and IPython

```
import IPython
url = 'https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/colorful-background-14.jpg'
IPython.display.Image(url, width = 250)
```

Unlike other methods, this method also works in a for loop!

Answer (score 31):

This answer was written for Python 2.7.

For Python 3, `urlopen` was moved from `urllib` to `urllib.requests`. And `StringIO.StringIO` was replaced by `io.BytesIO`.

Use `StringIO` to turn the read string into a file-like object:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image
import urllib

Image.open(StringIO(urllib.urlopen(url).read()))
```

Comment: This response is clean and helpful, but the import statement should read 
```from io import StringIO```

Comment: for Python 3, one would also need BytesIO not StringIO here:

`from io import BytesIO`

Answer (score 28):

The arguably *recommended* way to do image input/output these days is to use the dedicated package [ImageIO](https://imageio.github.io/). Image data can be read directly from a URL with one simple line of code:

```
from imageio import imread
image = imread('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/logo.png')
```

Many answers on this page predate the release of that package and therefore do not mention it. ImageIO started out as component of the [Scikit-Image](https://scikit-image.org/) toolkit. It supports a number of scientific formats on top of the ones provided by the popular image-processing library [PILlow](https://python-pillow.org/). It wraps it all in a clean API solely focused on image input/output. In fact, SciPy [removed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.3.0.html#scipy-interpolate-changes) its own image reader/writer [in favor of ImageIO](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html).

Comment: Very slow. skimage methods would be better option if you want to do in one line

Comment: This *is* the skimage (Scikit-Image) method, as the answer explains. And it's as slow as your internet connection.

Answer (score 24):

For those doing some sklearn/numpy post processing (i.e. Deep learning) you can wrap the PIL object with np.array(). This might save you from having to Google it like I did:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

response = requests.get(url)
img = np.array(Image.open(StringIO(response.content)))
```

Answer (score 5):

select the image in chrome, right click on it, click on `Copy image address`, paste it into a `str` variable (`my_url`) to read the image:

```
import shutil
import requests

my_url = 'https://www.washingtonian.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/6-30-17-goat-yoga-congressional-cemetery-1-994x559.jpg'
response = requests.get(my_url, stream=True)
with open('my_image.png', 'wb') as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, file)
del response
```

open it;

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('my_image.png')
img.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

> Manually wrapping in BytesIO is no longer needed since PIL >= 2.8.0. Just use Image.open(response.raw)

Adding on top of Vinícius's comment:

You should pass `stream=True` as noted https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content

So

```
img = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
```

Answer (score 3):

USE `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` AND `PIL.Image.open()` TO DOWNLOAD AND READ IMAGE DATA :

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import PIL

urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://i.imgur.com/ExdKOOz.png", "sample.png")
img = PIL.Image.open("sample.png")
img.show()
```

or Call requests.get(url) with url as the address of the object file to download via a GET request. Call io.BytesIO(obj) with obj as the content of the response to load the raw data as a bytes object. To load the image data, call PIL.Image.open(bytes_obj) with bytes_obj as the bytes object:

```
import io

response = requests.get("https://i.imgur.com/ExdKOOz.png")
image_bytes = io.BytesIO(response.content)
img = PIL.Image.open(image_bytes)
img.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
import requests
image=Image.open(requests.get("https://previews.123rf.com/images/darrenwhi/darrenwhi1310/darrenwhi131000024/24022179-photo-of-many-cars-with-one-a-different-color.jpg", stream=True).raw)
#image =resize((420,250))

image_array=np.array(image)
image
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Python 3 using OpenCV:**

```
import cv2
from urllib.request import urlopen

image_url = "IMAGE-URL-GOES-HERE"
resp = urlopen(image_url)
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) # The image object

# Optional: For testing & viewing the image
cv2.imshow('image',image)
```

**For Python 3 using OpenCV and Google Colab/Jupyter Notebook:**

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from urllib.request import urlopen

image_url = "IMAGE-URL-GOES-HERE"
resp = urlopen(image_url)
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) # The image object

# Optional: For testing & viewing the image
cv2_imshow(image)
```

Answer (score 1):

To directly get image as numpy array without using PIL

```
import requests, io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

response = requests.get(url).content
img = plt.imread(io.BytesIO(response), format='JPG')
plt.imshow(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions mentioned above might work, but it misses one point that I would like to highlight i.e. when we fetch or retrieve the image url to read, we might not always get the actual image content if we don't pass the **headers** while making the get request.

for example:

**request without Headers**

```
import requests
url = "https://www.roaringcreationsfilms.com/rcsfilms-media/chankya-quotes-in-hindi-32.jpg"
data = requests.get(url).content
```

if we check the data:

```
print(data)
b'<head><title>Not Acceptable!</title></head><body><h1>Not Acceptable!</h1><p>An 
appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server.
This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p></body></html>'
```

you see, we don't actually get the content of the image.

**request with Headers**

```
import requests
url = "https://www.roaringcreationsfilms.com/rcsfilms-media/chankya-quotes-in-hindi-32.jpg"
headers = {"User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.31.1"}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
```

and, if we now check the data:

```
print(data)
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\t\x06\x06\........\xfb\x04El\xb3\xa8L\xbc\xa12\xc6<\xc4\x891\xf2L|\xf7\x9eV\x18\xc5\xd8\x8f\x02\xca\xdc\xb1c+-\x96\'\x86\xcb,l\xb12;\x16\xd4j\xfd/\xde\xbf\xff\xd9'
```

Now, we get the actual content of the image.

Things to note are that different urls might require different combinations of the headers (such as "User-Agent", "Accept", "Accept-Encoding", etc.) to successfully get the data and some even might not require any headers. But it's always a good practice to pass "User-Agent" as a minimum required header while making the request.