# How to change the icon in the pygame window?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame

I am making use of pygame module to make games  but how do I change the default icon that appears on the Title Bar.

I am using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set the icon, you first need to load the image.

```
icon = pygame.image.load('image.png')
```

Next you use the image which you loaded, and set it as the icon.

```
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that , but also tell me how to load an image from a hyperlink such as from lorem-pixels website

Comment: @TilakMadichetti I'm not sure how you would do this with pygame, but take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python).

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for .. Thanks Bud !! Now you don't need to be "not sure" with your answer

Comment: @TilakMadichetti Glad I could help. We both learnt something new :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [set_icon()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_icon)? Never used pygame before but it seems the way to go.

Comment: To use set_icon() method , the documentary says that I should I pass a surface , but I want to load my own custom logo stored as ".png" file in the same directory instead of a surface

Comment: im also facing the same issue