# How do you perform a credentialed download from s3 using boto3 without saving a file?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

It is simple to perform a credentialed download from s3 to a file using

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
def save_file_from_s3(bucket_name, key_name, file_name):
    b = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    b.download_file(key_name, file_name)
```

It is easy to download from s3 to a file-like object using

```
import from StringIO import StringIO
import urllib

file_like_object = StringIO(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
```

(see [How do I read image data from a URL in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python))

But how do you perform a credentialed download from s3 to a file-like object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to make a call to [`s3.Bucket.Object.get`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.get):

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
# obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, key_name).get()
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
obj = bucket.Object(key_name).get()
body = obj.get('Body')
```

Comment: This returns a dictionary object.  But what I want is a file type object that I can then process, for example with Pillow.

Comment: The dictionary object contains the file object under the keyword "Body".

So to complete the example, just use 
    f = obj['Body']