# Best practice to download from s3 to client

Tags: file, amazon-s3, download

I'm using S3 to host my user's documents. My s3 bucket is not publically accessible. So my current implementation for that is,

- When the user presses download, make an API call from my application to S3 and get the file to `/tmp/` on my server.
- Send the file from `/tmp/` to the user's client as a browser download.

There is also a way to avoid saving to the server and directly sending the file to the client according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209938/how-do-you-perform-a-credentialed-download-from-s3-using-boto3-without-saving-a).

Which is the best practice? What are the disadvantages of sending a file object directly to the user?

Comment: I would suggest allowing the user to download directly, reducing load on your web server for static content. You can enforce authorisation for the download without needing to proxy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than make an API call to downloads the file locally, just generate a [presigned url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) and return a redirect to that url instead.

Comment: I didn't know about this. Thanks.