# How to web scrape images that are in a link in a table?

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

We need to get an image out a link of a table. there is a table, in there is a link en in that link are images. What is the best way to get all the images of the website?

Now we have the text out the table and the links:

But how do we get the images of this site?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/gestolen%20overzicht.htm"  # change to whatever your url is

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
link = soup.a

def main():
    """scrape some wikipedia"""

for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print "Datum: %s\n Plaats: %s\n Gestolen van: %s\n" %\
    (tds[0].text.strip(), tds[1].text.strip(), tds[2].text.strip())
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print link["href"]
    print link.renderContents()
```

Comment: What You are looking for is StringIO
have a look at eg.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the links with href's that include `images/...`, you can use a select using a [css-selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print([a["href"] for a in soup.select("a[href^=images/]")])
```

Which will give you:

```
[u'images/2015/eindhoven/eindhoven.htm', u'images/2015/rtl4/rtl4_schilderij%20gezocht.htm', u'images/2015/eindhoven/eindhoven.htm', u'images/2015/rtl4/rtl4_schilderij%20gezocht.htm', u'images/2015/doetinchem/doetinchem.htm', u'images/2014/emmeloord/emmeloord.htm', u'images/2014/heelsum/heelsum.htm', u'images/2014/blaricum/blaricum.htm', u'images/2014/hilversum/hilversum.htm', u'images/2014/kerkrade/kerkrade.htm', u'images/2013/heerhugowaard/artfarm.htm', u'images/2013/sittard/sittard.htm', u'images/2013/rotterdam/rotterdan.htm', u'images/2013/epe/epe.htm', u'images/2013/beek/beek.htm', u'images/2012/utrecht/utrecht.htm', u'images/2012/amsterdam/amsterdam.htm', u'images/2012/zwijndrecht/zwijdrecht.htm', u'images/2012/de_bilt/bakker.htm', u'images/2012/zutphen/zutphen.htm', u'images/2012/rheden/carmiggelt.htm', u'images/2012/dieren/dieren.htm', u'images/2011/denhaag/denhaag.htm', u'images/2011/rotterdam/bronzenbeeld_rotterdam.htm', u'images/2011/utrecht/utrecht.htm', u'images/2012/denhaag/denhaag.htm', u'images/2011/oosterbeek/oosterbeek.htm', u'images/2011/teruggevonden_alkmaar/sumo_worstelaar_brons.htm', u'images/2011/teruggevonden_alkmaar/sumo_worstelaar_brons.htm', u'images/2011/vlierden/vlierden.htm', u'images/2011/bergen/bergen.htm', u'images/2011/alkmaar/mca.htm', u'images/2010/hendrik_ido_ambacht/hendrik-ido-ambacht.htm', u'images/2010/nijmegen/nijmegen.htm', u'images/2010/heesch', u'images/2010/boxie/boxie_gestolen_powerbook.htm', u'images/2010/ijmuiden/ijmuiden_nic_jonk.htm', u'images/2010/jitsbakker/bakkerjuli2010.htm', u'images/2010/gouda/gouda.htm', u'images/2010/enschede/enschede.htm', u'images/2010/someren/someren.htm', u'images/2010/jitsbakker/jitsbakker_steltloper_maart2010.htm', u'images/2009/hogeweg/hogeweg.htm', u'images/2009/wildevuur/wildevuur.htm', u'images/2009/bad-nieuweschans/heus.htm', u'images/2009/bad-nieuweschans/heus.htm', u'images/2009/darp/kneulman.htm', u'images/2009/keramikos/keramikos.htm', u'images/2009/maasbracht/maasbracht.htm', u'images/2008/groet/groet.htm', u'images/2009/rotterdam/rotterdam.htm', u'images/2009/rotterdam/rotterdam.htm', u'images/2008/swifterband/swifterband.htm', u'images/2008/laren_snoek/laren_snoek.htm', u'images/2008/beetsterzwaag/Beetsterzwaag.htm', u'images/2008/callantsoog/booghaard.htm', u'images/2008/lelystad/lelystad.htm', u'images/2008/amsterdam_kok/amsterdam_kok.htm', u'images/2008/lochem/lochem.htm', u'images/2008/liempde/liempde.htm', u'images/2008/heerhugowaard/zande.htm', u'images/2008/amsterdam_hatterman/amsterdam_hatterman.htm', u'images/2008/delft/delft.htm', u'images/2008/sgraveland/sgraveland.htm', u'images/2008/laren/laren110308.htm', u'images/2008/laren/laren110308.htm', u'images/2008/alphen_ad_rijn/alphen_ad_rijn.htm', u'images/2008/hardinxveld/hardinxveld.htm', u'images/2008/denhaag_karres/denhaag_karres.htm', u'images/2008/amsterdam_eijsenberger/amsterdam_eijs.htm', u'images/2008/amsterdam/amsterdam.htm', u'images/2008/denhaag/denhaag_brauw.htm', u'images/2008/groenhart/groenhart.htm', u'images/2007/aalsmeer/aalsmeer.htm', u'images/2007/delft/delft_klaus.htm', u'images/2007/malden/malden.htm', u'images/2007/sterksel/sterksel.htm', u'images/2007/zeist/zeist_achmea.htm', u'images/2007/maaseik_laar/maaseik.htm', u'images/2007/meerssen/meerssen.htm', u'images/2007/lisse/lisse.htm', u'images/2007/kortenhoef/kortenhoef.htm', u'images/2007/schijndel/schijndel.htm', u'images/2007/alkmaar/smit.htm', u'images/2007/heerlen/heerlen.htm', u'images/2007/heerlen/heerlen.htm', u'images/2007/tiel/kaayk.htm', u'images/2007/arnhem/arnhem.htm', u'images/2007/amsterdam_noort/amsterdam_noort.htm', u'images/2007/sgravenhage/sgravenhage.htm', u'images/2007/hazelaar/hazelaar.htm', u'images/2007/putte-stabroek/putte_stabroek.htm', u'images/2007/maarssen/maarssen_beeldentuin.htm', u'images/2007/huizen/huizen_gemeente.htm', u'images/2007/Maastricht_laar/maastricht_laar.htm', u'images/2007/bilthoven/bilthoven_v.htm', u'images/2007/sypesteyn/sypesteyn.htm', u'images/2007/hulzen/hulzen.htm', u'images/2007/huizen_limieten/huizen_limieten.htm', u'images/2007/elburg/elburg_galerie.htm', u'images/2007/hasselt/schildwacht_hasselt.htm', u'images/2006/woerden/woerden.htm', u'images/2006/amsterdam_slotervaart/sheils.htm', u'images/2006/recr_klepperstee_ouddorp/klepperstee_ouddorp.htm', u'images/2006/recr_klepperstee_ouddorp/klepperstee_ouddorp.htm', u'images/2007/erichem/krol.htm', u'images/2006/someren/someren.htm', u'images/2006/sliedrecht/sliedrecht_jitsbakker.htm', u'images/2006/blank/blank_2006.htm', u'images/2006/kemps_eindhoven/kemps_eindhoven.htm', u'images/2006/schoorl/begraafplaats_diels.htm', u'images/2006/bloemendaal/bloemendaal.htm', u'images/2010/zwolle/zwolle_leeser.htm', u'images/2006/vinkeveen/vinkeveen_jozefschool.htm', u'images/2006/gemeente_bergen/gemeente_bergen.htm', u'images/2006/alphen_ad_rijn/alphenadrijn.htm', u'images/2006/alphen_ad_rijn/alphenadrijn.htm', u'images/2006/Nieuwegein/nieuwegein.htm', u'images/2006/alkmaar_lange/lange.htm', u'images/2006/janneman/janneman.htm', u'images/2006/schoffelen/schoffelen.htm', u'images/2006/keuenhof_ede/keuenhof.htm', u'images/2006/rucphen/rucphen.htm', u'images/2006/lemberger_amsterdam/lemberger.htm', u'images/2006/bronckhorst/bronckhorst.htm', u'images/2006/arnhem_peja/peja.htm', u'images/2005/klomp/klomp.htm', u'images/2005/kalverda/kalverda.htm', u'images/2005/schellekens/schellekens.htm', u'images/2005/beeldhouwwinkel/beeldhouwwinkel.htm', u'images/2005/huisman/huisman.htm', u'images/2005/lith/lith.htm', u'images/2005/bergen/bergen_onna.htm', u'images/2005/emst_remeeus/emst.htm', u'images/2005/water/water.htm', u'images/2005/maastricht_drielsma/maastricht_drielsma.htm', u'images/2005/bosch/bosch.htm', u'images/2005/fransen/fransen.htm', u'images/vaart/vaart.htm', u'images/2005/lammertink/lammertink.htm', u'images/brocke/brocke.htm', u'images/wood/wood.htm', u'images/2005/klijzing/klijzing.htm', u'images/metalart/ponsioen.htm', u'images/harderwijk/harderwijk.htm', u'images/gulpen/gulpen.htm', u'images/limburg/limburg.htm', u'images/landgraaf/landgraaf.htm', u'images/pijnappel.htm', u'images/termaat/termaat.htm', u'images/vries/vries.htm', u'images/hartigh/hartigh.htm', u'images/hengelo/hengelo.htm', u'images/nijmegen/teunen/teunen.htm', u'images/nijmegen/nijmegen.htm', u'images/hollants/hollants_carla.htm', u'images/laren/laren_gils.htm', u'images/2003/smakt/smakt.htm', u'images/koopman/koopman.htm', u'images/voorschoten/voorschoten.htm', u'images/hagen/hagen.htm', u'images/bakker/gestolen%20kunst%20Jits%20Bakker.htm', u'images/bliekendaal/bliekendaal.htm', u'images/2003/utrecht/utrecht.htm', u'images/davina/davina.htm', u'images/janneman/janneman.htm', u'images/dijk/dijk.htm', u'images/clarissenbolwerk/havermans.htm', u'images/appelhof/appelhof.htm', u'images/blank/blank.htm', u'images/dussen/dussen.htm', u'images/bakker/gestolen%20kunst%20Jits%20Bakker.htm', u'images/rijs/rijs.htm', u'images/janssen', u'images/bakker/gestolen%20kunst%20Jits%20Bakker.htm', u'images/2002/nijssen/ouderamstel_nijssen.htm', u'images/onna/onna.htm', u'images/haring/haring.htm', u'images/dijk/dijk.htm', u'images/janneman/janneman.htm', u'images/hessels/hessels.htm', u'images/onna/onna.htm', u'images/2012/culemborg/culemborg_1998.htm', u'images/1998/mierlo/mierlo.htm', u'images/oud/wigbold/wigbold.htm', u'images/oud/nijmegen/nijmegen.htm', u'images/oud/amsterdam_ommen/amstedam_ommen.htm']
```

`a[href^=images/]` simply means find all the anchor tags that have a href attribute where tha value starts with `images/..`, then we just pull the href from each anchor.

To use the links you will need to join the link to the main url:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse  import urljoin
url = "http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/gestolen%20overzicht.htm"  # change to whatever your url is
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

base = "http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/"

images = [urljoin(base,a["href"]) for a in soup.select("a[href^=images/]")]

print(images)
```

Output:

```
[u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2015/eindhoven/eindhoven.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2015/rtl4/rtl4_schilderij%20gezocht.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2015/eindhoven/eindhoven.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2015/rtl4/rtl4_schilderij%20gezocht.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2015/doetinchem/doetinchem.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2014/emmeloord/emmeloord.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2014/heelsum/heelsum.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2014/blaricum/blaricum.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2014/hilversum/hilversum.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2014/kerkrade/kerkrade.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2013/heerhugowaard/artfarm.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2013/sittard/sittard.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2013/rotterdam/rotterdan.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2013/epe/epe.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2013/beek/beek.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2012/utrecht/utrecht.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2012/amsterdam/amsterdam.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2012/zwijndrecht/zwijdrecht.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2012/de_bilt/bakker.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2012/zutphen/zutphen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2012/rheden/carmiggelt.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2012/dieren/dieren.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2011/denhaag/denhaag.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2011/rotterdam/bronzenbeeld_rotterdam.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2011/utrecht/utrecht.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2012/denhaag/denhaag.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2011/oosterbeek/oosterbeek.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2011/teruggevonden_alkmaar/sumo_worstelaar_brons.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2011/teruggevonden_alkmaar/sumo_worstelaar_brons.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2011/vlierden/vlierden.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2011/bergen/bergen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2011/alkmaar/mca.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2010/hendrik_ido_ambacht/hendrik-ido-ambacht.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2010/nijmegen/nijmegen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2010/heesch', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2010/boxie/boxie_gestolen_powerbook.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2010/ijmuiden/ijmuiden_nic_jonk.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2010/jitsbakker/bakkerjuli2010.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2010/gouda/gouda.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2010/enschede/enschede.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2010/someren/someren.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2010/jitsbakker/jitsbakker_steltloper_maart2010.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2009/hogeweg/hogeweg.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2009/wildevuur/wildevuur.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2009/bad-nieuweschans/heus.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2009/bad-nieuweschans/heus.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2009/darp/kneulman.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2009/keramikos/keramikos.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2009/maasbracht/maasbracht.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/groet/groet.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2009/rotterdam/rotterdam.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2009/rotterdam/rotterdam.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/swifterband/swifterband.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/laren_snoek/laren_snoek.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/beetsterzwaag/Beetsterzwaag.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/callantsoog/booghaard.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/lelystad/lelystad.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/amsterdam_kok/amsterdam_kok.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/lochem/lochem.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/liempde/liempde.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/heerhugowaard/zande.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/amsterdam_hatterman/amsterdam_hatterman.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/delft/delft.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/sgraveland/sgraveland.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/laren/laren110308.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/laren/laren110308.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/alphen_ad_rijn/alphen_ad_rijn.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/hardinxveld/hardinxveld.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/denhaag_karres/denhaag_karres.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/amsterdam_eijsenberger/amsterdam_eijs.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/amsterdam/amsterdam.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/denhaag/denhaag_brauw.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2008/groenhart/groenhart.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/aalsmeer/aalsmeer.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/delft/delft_klaus.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/malden/malden.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/sterksel/sterksel.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/zeist/zeist_achmea.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/maaseik_laar/maaseik.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/meerssen/meerssen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/lisse/lisse.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/kortenhoef/kortenhoef.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/schijndel/schijndel.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/alkmaar/smit.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/heerlen/heerlen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/heerlen/heerlen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/tiel/kaayk.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/arnhem/arnhem.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/amsterdam_noort/amsterdam_noort.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/sgravenhage/sgravenhage.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/hazelaar/hazelaar.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/putte-stabroek/putte_stabroek.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/maarssen/maarssen_beeldentuin.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/huizen/huizen_gemeente.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/Maastricht_laar/maastricht_laar.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/bilthoven/bilthoven_v.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/sypesteyn/sypesteyn.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/hulzen/hulzen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/huizen_limieten/huizen_limieten.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/elburg/elburg_galerie.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/hasselt/schildwacht_hasselt.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/woerden/woerden.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/amsterdam_slotervaart/sheils.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/recr_klepperstee_ouddorp/klepperstee_ouddorp.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/recr_klepperstee_ouddorp/klepperstee_ouddorp.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2007/erichem/krol.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/someren/someren.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/sliedrecht/sliedrecht_jitsbakker.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/blank/blank_2006.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/kemps_eindhoven/kemps_eindhoven.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/schoorl/begraafplaats_diels.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/bloemendaal/bloemendaal.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2010/zwolle/zwolle_leeser.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/vinkeveen/vinkeveen_jozefschool.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/gemeente_bergen/gemeente_bergen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/alphen_ad_rijn/alphenadrijn.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/alphen_ad_rijn/alphenadrijn.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/Nieuwegein/nieuwegein.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/alkmaar_lange/lange.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/janneman/janneman.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/schoffelen/schoffelen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/keuenhof_ede/keuenhof.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/rucphen/rucphen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/lemberger_amsterdam/lemberger.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/bronckhorst/bronckhorst.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2006/arnhem_peja/peja.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/klomp/klomp.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/kalverda/kalverda.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/schellekens/schellekens.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/beeldhouwwinkel/beeldhouwwinkel.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/huisman/huisman.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/lith/lith.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/bergen/bergen_onna.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/emst_remeeus/emst.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/water/water.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/maastricht_drielsma/maastricht_drielsma.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/bosch/bosch.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/fransen/fransen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/vaart/vaart.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/lammertink/lammertink.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/brocke/brocke.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/wood/wood.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2005/klijzing/klijzing.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/metalart/ponsioen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/harderwijk/harderwijk.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/gulpen/gulpen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/limburg/limburg.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/landgraaf/landgraaf.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/pijnappel.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/termaat/termaat.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/vries/vries.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/hartigh/hartigh.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/hengelo/hengelo.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/nijmegen/teunen/teunen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/nijmegen/nijmegen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/hollants/hollants_carla.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/laren/laren_gils.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2003/smakt/smakt.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/koopman/koopman.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/voorschoten/voorschoten.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/hagen/hagen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/bakker/gestolen%20kunst%20Jits%20Bakker.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/bliekendaal/bliekendaal.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2003/utrecht/utrecht.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/davina/davina.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/janneman/janneman.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/dijk/dijk.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/clarissenbolwerk/havermans.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/appelhof/appelhof.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/blank/blank.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/dussen/dussen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/bakker/gestolen%20kunst%20Jits%20Bakker.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/rijs/rijs.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/janssen', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/bakker/gestolen%20kunst%20Jits%20Bakker.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2002/nijssen/ouderamstel_nijssen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/onna/onna.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/haring/haring.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/dijk/dijk.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/janneman/janneman.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/hessels/hessels.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/onna/onna.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2012/culemborg/culemborg_1998.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/1998/mierlo/mierlo.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/oud/wigbold/wigbold.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/oud/nijmegen/nijmegen.htm', u'http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/oud/amsterdam_ommen/amstedam_ommen.htm']
```

You could be more specific with the select using the td `"td a[href^=images/]"` but it will return the same as all those links are in td tags.

The actually image are in the linked pages so we need to visit each link, find the img tag, extract the src then download and save the image:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse  import urljoin
url = "http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/gestolen%20overzicht.htm"  # change to whatever your url is
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

base = "http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/"

images = [urljoin(base,a["href"]) for a in soup.select("td a[href^=images/]")]

for url in images:
    img = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(),"lxml").find("img")["src"]
    with open(img,"w") as f:
        f.write(urllib2.urlopen("{}/{}".format(url.rsplit("/", 1)[0], img)).read())
```

So for `http://www.gestolenkunst.nl/images/2015/eindhoven/eindhoven.htm` we get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Now you print it en you get:

[u'images/2015/eindhoven/eindhoven.htm', u'images/2015/rtl4/rtl4_schilderij%20gezocht.htm',]

Can you get the images in a folder that you can see them? Now you can not see the image.

Comment: You need to download the image using those links and save