# File exists but still getting FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

File exists but still getting FileNotFoundError

```
with open(r"C:\Users\zafre\OneDrive\Desktop\monthlySalesbyCategoryMultiple.json") as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
```

Comment: The `open` function takes a filesystem path, not a URL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875095/python-open-says-file-doesnt-exist-when-it-does

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python open says file doesn't exist when it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875095/python-open-says-file-doesnt-exist-when-it-does)

Comment: Do you still have an error?