# Python - how to read an image from a URL?

Tags: python

I am completely new to Python and I'm trying to figure out how to read an image from a URL.

Here is my current code:

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request, io

URL = 'http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'

with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as url:
    s = url.read()
    Image.open(s)
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\python>python image.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image.py", line 8, in <module>
    Image.open(s)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2272, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

I have no idea what any of this means. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `open()` expects file name, not data - so you have to write image locally and then open it - `Image.open('temp.jpg')`. Or use io.BytesIO to create file object in memory.

Comment: What do you want to do with the image once you have read it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Image.open()` expects `filename` or `file-like object` - not `file data`.

You can write image locally - i.e. as `"temp.jpg"` - and then open it

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request

URL = 'http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'

with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as url:
    with open('temp.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(url.read())

img = Image.open('temp.jpg')

img.show()
```

Or you can create `file-like object` in memory using `io` module

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request
import io

URL = 'http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'

with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as url:
    f = io.BytesIO(url.read())

img = Image.open(f)

img.show()
```

---

**EDIT: 2022**

Because `urlopen()` also gives `file-like object` so you can even skip `io` and use directly `url` (without `.read()`) in `Image.open()`

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request

URL = 'http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'

with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as url:
    img = Image.open(url)
    img.show()
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to read an image from a URL using [**scikit-image**](http://scikit-image.org/)

```
from skimage import io

io.imshow(io.imread("http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"))
io.show()
```

---

Note: [io.imread()](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread) returns a numpy array

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, you may download the image to your current working directory first

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'
urlretrieve(url, 'pic.jpg')
```

And then open/read it locally:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('pic.jpg')

# For example, check image size and format
print(img.size)
print(img.format)

img.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this approach:

```
import urllib.request
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

URL = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/161px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg'

with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as url:
    imgfile = BytesIO(url.read())
    img = plt.imread(imgfile,format='jpeg')

plt.imshow(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python), you can do something like this:

```
import urllib, cStringIO
from PIL import Image

file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(URL).read())
img = Image.open(file)
```

Then you can use your image freely.
For example, you can convert it to a numpy array:

```
img_npy = np.array(img)
```