# Download a Jpeg image given a URL into numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy, url, jpeg

Using python, I would like to download a Jpeg image given a URL and stored it in a `numpy` array for processing later. What library should I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - how to read an image from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911170/python-how-to-read-an-image-from-a-url)

Comment: Try scikit-image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40911860/6018688 i.e. `from skimage import io; io.imread(url)`

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of libraries that can be used for this task. The one that I've used in the past is from `scikit-image`:

```
import skimage

image_filename = "http://example.com/example.jpg"
image_numpy = skimage.io.imread( image_filename )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use either `request` library or `wget`library to handle download the image. And then use cv2 to open as numpy array

`wget` is faster, `pip install wget`

Example (wget):

```
import cv2, wget
image_url = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'
filename = wget.download(image_url)
np_image = cv2.imread(filename)
```

Example (request)

```
import requests, io, cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')
bytes_im = io.BytesIO(response.content)
cv_im = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(Image.open(bytes_im)), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

Comment: Do you mind adding the example using request?

Comment: @Anjayluh Here you go