# opening a JPG file in Google Colab

Tags: python

I have this code in to open a PNG file on google colab.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from PIL import Image
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread('https://www.seekpng.com/png/full/161-1615982_doc-back-to-the- 
future-png-doc-back.png')

imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
```

The problem is that this code only works for PNG files. I have trouble opening a JPG file, and a GIF file in Google Colab. I would like to open a picture with its image address from the web, just like the one from the previous code.
I know you can open JPG files with this code.

```
from PIL import Image                                                                                
img = Image.open("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/Girl_in_front_of_a_green_background.jpg")
img.show()
```

but it gives me the following error when compiling. **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911170/python-how-to-read-an-image-from-a-url)

a summary:

you need to retrieve the jpg or any kind of file save and then read it from it's path for the Image.open() function

using requests you can get

[this](https://www.codespeedy.com/read-image-from-url-in-python/) might be useful too.