# How to read bytes from a image url (jpeg) and encode in base64 on Python 2.7?

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I am using the following code:

```
import urllib, cStringIO
from PIL import Image  
url='https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'
file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
img = Image.open(file)
```

based on: [How do I read image data from a URL in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python)

Now I need to base64 encode it for posting to Google Cloud Vision API. How to do that?

Or does the Google Cloud vision API work with image urls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's no need to parse the image, just grab it and encode it:

```
import urllib2
import base64
url = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'
contents = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
data = base64.b64encode(contents)
print data
```