# Image GUI sourced from Internet Python

Tags: python

I am trying to display an image from a Url however i am not sure how to do so.
Below is my attempt:

```
imageFile = "http://photo.elsoar.com/wp-content/images/Personal-computer.jpg"
image1 =PhotoImage(open(imageFile))
image1.grid(row=1, column=5)
```

This just produces an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Derren\Desktop\Online Shopper.py", line 131, in <module>
image1 =PhotoImage(open(imageFile))
```

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'http://photo.elsoar.com/wp-content/images/Personal-computer.jpg'
This is the image i want to have
http://photo.elsoar.com/wp-content/images/Personal-computer.jpg

However it is essential that it is resourced from the internet and not local files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read image data from a URL in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python)

Comment: you should use `urllib` (as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python) or use a similar approach

Comment: This returns Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Derren\Desktop\Online Shopper.py", line 132, in <module>
    img = Image.open(imgfile)
AttributeError: class Image has no attribute 'open'

Answer (score 0):

The function open() only works on locals files. You can see doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) part 7.2. If you want to work with an online image, you can use this :

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get("url")
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img.save("my_img.png") #with the good filename extension
```

Comment: No module called PIL

Comment: To use import PIL, you must install librairie [PILLOW](https://python-pillow.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you particularly want a `PhotoImage` based solution that this should work:

```
import urllib

f = urllib.urlopen("http://photo.elsoar.com/wp-content/images/Personal-computer.jpg")
data=f.read()
root = Tkinter.Tk()
image1 =PhotoImage(data)
```

Comment: How do i add this to a GUI,the grid function doesn't work

Comment: f = urllib.urlopen("http://photo.elsoar.com/wp-content/images/Personal-computer.jpg")
data=f.read()
image1 =PhotoImage(data)
image1.grid(row=1,column=1)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Derren\Desktop\Online Shopper.py", line 134, in <module>
    image1.grid(row=1,column=1)
AttributeError: PhotoImage instance has no attribute 'grid'