# Get photos from URL and paste to WORD or PDF

Tags: python, pdf, url, ms-word

I have an excel file with 3 columns: id, url1 and url2. Both url1 and url2 contain the URL of an image.

How to get the images and paste to WORD and PDF in a table format? There are 3 columns: id, image from url1 and image from url2.

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
document = Document()
p = document.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
r.add_picture('a.jpg')#OK
url = r'http://www.example.com/a.jpg'
r.add_picture(urllib.request.urlopen(url))#fail, how to do it?

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can look into: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html to read the excel file.
2. You can use a simple for loop to loop through the data.
3. You can use http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ to send a get request to the url and receive the image.
4. You can use https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.0.0/ to manipulate the image.
5. You can use http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html to save to the word file.

I can't however do all the work for you.

Edit: 
I haven't really used urllib, but I can download an image using requests by

```
 x = requests.get("https://www.pythonsheets.com/_static/guido.png")
```

I can then open the file using:

```
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO
Image.open(StringIO(x.content)).show()
```

So, that shows I can open download the image file using requests. You can try saving `x.content` in the word document.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried to do what you suggested but the problem is inserting an image in the url. How to do that?

Comment: This can help you as well. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import io
import urllib
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()
p = document.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
url = r'http://www.example.com/a.jpg'
io_url = io.BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
r.add_picture(io_url)
document.save('demo.docx')
```

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion, Frankie.

Comment: throws :
---> 30 from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
     31 from warnings import warn
     32 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'

in from docx import Document