# Read an image using url imageio python

Tags: python-3.5, python-imageio

Can anyone tell how to read an image using an URL given, with the help of imageio python3?
I have already looked at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python) but is it possible to use imageio instead of PIL.