# How to import data from the web as a photo?

Tags: python

I've looked for this question but I haven't come to a result at all. I know that it is possible to **scrape**/import web data to python, but usually the data format/set doesn't look like the visited webpage. So my question is: Is it possible at all to make a code in python to make a screenshot from a certain web page and to import it into the program?

I know that it is possible to import pictures to python, but can it also make automatically screenshots, maybe this question already exists and I haven't seen it, my apologies, in that case, I will delete this question.

Thank you very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23489503/12485722

Comment: That's not really what I was looking for, but thank you, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be using selenium `driver.save_screenshot()` to take a screenshot, i.e.:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://duckduckgo.com/')
ss_name = "duckduckgo.png"
driver.save_screenshot(ss_name)
driver.quit()

with open(ss_name, "rb") as f:
    for line in f:
        pass
        # do something with the screenshot binary data
```

---

## duckduckgo.png

[image: duckduckgo.png]

Comment: So if I understood it correctly, this program makes screenshots from every website, saves it and when the code is expanded, it could open it in the programm. Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, that's a correct assumption.  If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer and give it 1+, thanks!