# How can I use httplib2 to upload an image, but not save it to my computer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, httplib2

How can I use httplib2 to receiving images from the site, but not save it to my computer, but at the same time so that I can use it. My code is:

```
h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
response, content = h.request(self.url + 'v1588505946/images/mc-donalds_vexbhd.png')
out = open('images2/' + self.names[1], 'wb')
out.write(content) # How to avoid this line
out.close()
self.img1 = Image.open('images2/' + self.names[1]) # Here I want to open the image directly from the server
self.img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img1)
```

Comment: Upload?In your example,it seems that you want to download a image.

Comment: Just the problem is that in my example the file is saved on the PC, but I need it to open directly without downloading

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BytesIO` to convert it directly,then you could use `Image.open` to open it directly.
example:

```
from io import BytesIO

...

response, content = h.request(self.url + 'v1588505946/images/mc-donalds_vexbhd.png')
self.img1 = Image.open(BytesIO(content))
```