# Python class ("name 'fetch' is not defined")

Tags: python, class

I'm writing a python program, which should fetch images from the internet. Therefore I created a main controller and an APIService. Because I want to make the controller more light, I added some functionallity into the APIServices.

Unfortunally I cant call other functions within the APIService Class, I always get the error: ("name 'fetch' is not defined").

Is there a way to call methods inside a class or isnt this supported in python?

Code example:

```
class APIService(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
         #init

    def fetch(url):
        #fetch Image 

    def fetchLogic(self, url):
          for i in url:
               fetch(i)    #here the error accures 



class Controller(object):        
      def __init__(self):
          #init

      def callAPI()
          api = APIService("url")
          api.fetchLogic([url1,url2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Controller()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `self.fetch(i)` instead of `fetch(i)`, aswell as accept the `self` argument in the decleration of `fetch`:

```
def fetch(self, url):
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `self.fetch(i)` instead of `fetch(i)` to access the method of the class instance.

Comment: there's also an issue with how `fetch` is defined. it's not a `@staticmethod`, so you also need to update the signature to `def fetch(self, url)` or add a `@staticmethod` decorator

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in there

```
def fetch(url):
    # fetch image
```

The fetch function does not return anything.

You have to code `fetch` function

```
def fetch(url):
    print('Supposed to fetch image, but return nothing now')
```

or you could do

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO


def fetch(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    return img
```

Thanks to [@AndreasKuli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python) for the answer