# How to open and display images from a github repository

Tags: python, image, github, python-imaging-library, display

I've already created a public repository containing some images . How can I open them and display them ? I'm guessing with the use of `pyplot` somehow . Here's what I've tried :

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('https://github.com/TeoOG/Computer_Vision_Assistance/blob/master/images/image1.jpg')
image.show()
```

Also here's my repository's link :
https://github.com/TeoOG/Computer_Vision_Assistance

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python

Comment: You need to provide the raw URL.which in your case is `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeoOG/Computer_Vision_Assistance/master/images/image1.jpg`.

Comment: Also you need something like a URL parser like the thread mentioned above to actually get the data as `Image.open` will only accept local file pointers.

Answer (score 1):

okay it's done :

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeoOG/Computer_Vision_Assistance/master/images/image1.jpg'

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))


img.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If still not working add '?raw=true' at the end of any GitHub image URL,
it will auto-generate raw image to load.

```
image = Image.open('https://github.com/TeoOG/Computer_Vision_Assistance/blob/master/images/image1.jpg?raw=true')
```