# (Discord.py) Read in a image from the attachment url and display it

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I was able to get the URL from the attachment and send back the image to the discord server, but when it came to displaying the image through the Pycharm IDE, I was not able to do so.

I tried using matplotlib and skimage to display the image but to no avail.

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
from discord import Embed
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello')
  if message.attachments[0].url.endswith('png') or message.attachments[0].url.endswith('jpg') or message.attachments[0].url.endswith('jpeg'):
    await message.channel.send('This is a picture') #check if the attachment is a image
    url = message.attachments[0].url  # get the url to the attached image
    e = discord.Embed()
    e.set_image(url=message.attachments[0].url)
    await message.channel.send(embed=e) # embed the image and send it back to the discord channel
    #try to display the image
    image = io.imread(url)
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

[Re-Upload Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yS9j.jpg)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'displaying the image'? Showing it in the app?

Answer (score -1):

We can directly use requests to load the url.

```py
import requests
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yS9j.jpg"
im = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
imshow(np.asarray(im))
```

### References:

- [Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python)

Comment: Thx, but I used this to display the image-> plt.imshow(image) // plt.show()

Comment: If something worked, it's better you answer the question so other users that might face the same problem know how you solved it.