# How do you find the filetype of an image in a url with nonobvious filetype in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, url, file-type

Certain CDNs like googleusercontent don't (obviously) encode the filenames of images in their urls, so you can't get the filetype from simply using string manipulation like other answers here have suggested. knowing this, how can tell that

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AM-JKLURvu-Ro2N3c1vm1PTM3a7Ae5nG3LNWynuKNEeFNBMwH_uWLQJe0q0HmaOzKC0k0gRba10SbonLaheGcNpxROnCenf1YJnzDC3jL-N9fTtZ7u0q5Z-3iURXtrt4GlyeEI3t4KWxprFDqFWRO29sJc8=w440-h248-no

is a gif whilst

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AM-JKLXk2WxafqHOi0ZrETUh2vUNkiLyYW1jRmAQsHBmYyVP7Le-KBCSVASCgO2C6_3QbW3LcLYOV_8OefPafyz2i4g8nqpw8xZnIhzDdemd5dFPS5A7dVAGQWx9DIy5aYOGuh06hTrmfhF9mZmITjjTwuc=w1200-h600-no

is a jpg

Comment: Download at least the first few bytes of the file. Most formats begin with a sequence of "magic bytes" to identify format like "GIF" or "JFIF".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the responses to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python), you could try:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image       # pillow package
from io import BytesIO

url = "your link"

image = Image.open( BytesIO( requests.get( url ).content))
file_type = image.format
```

This calls for downloading the entire file, though. If you're looking to do this in bulk, you might want to explore the option in the comment above that mentions "magic bytes"...

Edit:
You can also try to get the image type from the headers of the response to your url:

```
headers = requests.get(url).headers
file_type =headers.get('Content-Type', "nope/nope").split("/")[1]
# Will print 'nope' if 'Content-Type' header isn't found
print(file_type)
# Will print 'gif' or 'jpeg' for your listed urls
```

Edit 2:
If you're really only concerned with the file type of the link and not the file itself, you could use the `head` method instead of the `get` method of the requests module. It's faster:

```
headers = requests.head(url).headers
file_type =headers.get('Content-Type', "nope/nope").split("/")[1]
```