# I am trying to resize a url image in tkinter python, can any one help me how can I do this

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Top Movies of The Week")
screen.config(padx=50, pady=50, bg="red")

image_url = "https://m.media-amazon.com/imag/M/MV5BYTRiNDQwYzAtMzVlZS00NTI5LWJjYjUtMzkwNTUzMWMxZTllXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDIzMzcwNjc@._V1_.jpg"
u = urlopen(image_url)
raw_data = u.read()

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=raw_data)

label = Label(image=photo)
label.pack()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Look at how to use the `PIL` image library. It has a resize method and also has `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` to convert the image to `tkinter`

Comment: i have tried can you please tell me where i apply resize

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23489503/11106801) but add `.resize((<width>, <height>))` at the end of `Image.open(...)`. To add the image to `tkinter`, look it up online

Comment: `resized = Image.Open(u).resize((width, height))`, then `photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)`.

Comment: its working brother thanks alot i have no words to thank you