# Display an image from a URL using request()

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries containing data on products. Each product has one image URL. The data looks very much like below:

```py
products_dicts = [
  {
    "uniq_id": "123987",
    "sku": "123",
    "name": "ABC",
    "cat": "DEF",
    "cat_tree": "A|B|C",
    "image_urls": "http://sitecom/image1.tif"
  },
  {
    "uniq_id": "987123",
    "sku": "987",
    "name": "GHI",
    "cat": "JKL",
    "cat_tree": "Z|Y|X",
    "image_urls": "http://sitecom/img/image2.tif"
  }
]
```

I want to use the `urllib.request()` to retrieve the image and display it for `product` with the `uniq_id` equals to `123987`. I have started with the following:

```py
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image

q = [x['product_image_urls'] for x in products_dicts if x['uniq_id'] == '123987']
```

Comment: And also this one: [How do I read image data from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url)

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]