# Image URL to Blurhash Key in Python Flask

Tags: python, image, flask

How to I convert an online image url to a blurhash key in python flask ? The official documentation only shows code for local image files.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. Blurhash has its library for Python:

https://github.com/woltapp/blurhash-python

```py
import blurhash

with open('image.jpg', 'rb') as image_file:
    hash = blurhash.encode(image_file, x_components=4, y_components=3)
```

Comment: Ok but how do I use a network image file in it ? The snippet seems to work for local file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python

Comment: I got a utf8 error saying something about '0xff' code tried to do encoding="utf-16" or errors="ignore" as suggested by some other answers but it isn't working.